# jQuery hide/show/toggle/empty

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can't get this jQuery to work. I have a paragraph inside of a div. When a div tab/button is clicked, I want it `hide()` the paragraph. When the opposite div tab/button is pushed, I want to `show()` it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sketchs/FB28D/2/

```js
$("#details").on("click", function () {
    $(".cont").hide();
    $("#content").text("some text");
});
$("#description").on("click", function () {
    $("#content").empty();
    $("p.cont").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might fine it easier to use a JQuery plugin for this rather than write the code yourself.

JQuery UI is brilliant for this kind of stuff, see the tabs section here:

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

as you only want it for Tabs you can get a custom download of it here which will reduce the amount of code you load on the page:

http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.3&components=1100000000000000001000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing anything because you're emptying out the `#content` div and then trying to show its child:

```
$("#content").empty();
```

Will clear out anything inside the selector. So a quick `console.log($("p.cont").length)` is 0, since you've cleared it. Just change the text or don't empty it.

Comment: I removed the empty command and it's still not bringing back the P

Comment: @user3058518 You're also replacing the p with "some text" in your other handler http://jsfiddle.net/FB28D/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you end up opting to write your own tab script, there are lots of ways to solve the problem even with Jquery. Here's one way:

(http://jsfiddle.net/ruqmU/5/)

**CSS**

```
.tab {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:.5em;
}
#contentArea {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding:.5em;
    clear: both;
}
.block {display:block;}
.hide {display:none;}
.selectedTab {background-color:red;}
```

**Javascript (Jquery)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // default first tab to visible
    $('.content').addClass('hide');
    $('.content').first().removeClass('hide').addClass('block');
    $('.tab').first().addClass('selectedTab');

    // on click, hide all content except content matching the clicked tab
    $('.tab').click(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('selectedTab')) {
            var tabContentType = $(this).children('p').attr('class');
            $('.tab').removeClass('selectedTab');
            $(this).addClass('selectedTab');
            $('div.content').addClass('hide');
            $( '.' + tabContentType ).parent().removeClass('hide').addClass('block');
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabArea">
    <div class="tab">
        <p class="details">details</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <p class="description">description</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="contentArea">
    <div class="content">
        <p class="details">details go here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p class="description">description goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I opted for an uglier way of doing it. I made 2 paragraphs. Hid one on load. Then just swapped the hide/show for each button. Very ugly indeed.

Comment: Cool. The above isn't real pretty, either.